# Laravel mysql database crash on bigger size with newFromBuilder() error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, memory

I have a large database around 12mb size, and at that size Laravel is giving me 500 internal error. In smaller sizes it works nice.
I have found this error in logs but with no additional info:

```
PHP  54. Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->newFromBuilder()
```

From my search it can be that I need to insert `DB::disableQueryLog();`  code somewhere but I am not sure exactly where?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are the same guy who ask the question in Laracasts ([Laravel and mysql database crash on bigger size?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-and-mysql-database-crash-on-bigger-size-giving-newfrombuilder-error)).

But if you aren't and you have a low ram server, you should try to increase the size of the ram.

Let us know if it works.